# WCF service giving error on production server

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-client

Am facing a strange issue on my Production Server.
M calling a WCF service to get data and getting exception

```
Timestamp: 4/22/2011 9:50:01 AM
Message: System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at [ServiceAdress] that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond [Server IP]
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

For testing purpose and to get  actual exception , i made an Console application and just call that service.I m geting result when i run that on local + Development server and console application runs fine, but when i run that on My production server it gives this error.

I would like to know is there any thing i need to check on my production Envirnment?
I have check and there is no Firewall there (chances that firewall is blocking that) but there is no fire wall at all..

Do help me is there any thing i can check /do in order to run mu application??

Regards and thanks

****EDIT****

One thing i like to add here is that. My Web Site is hosted there and that web site is calling that service and geting exception. To make it simple , i made an Console application in what m calling that service and run that on Both Dev and Production (where webSite is hosted).

Console appliaction runs fine on Development
Console appliaction gives error on Production

Comment: How is the service hosted? what are the diffrences between you local and prod servers.

Comment: Maybe you are using HTTPS on the live server?

Comment: My website's aspx page is calling that service. That web site is on some other server.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the endpoint addresses for the following:
Protocol your are using and endpoint address with port defined in service and client.

If your are using WAS for this then check setting defined for the service by right clicking on the service in defined application pool. Also test the endpoint address defined in the IE also, if it shows OUTput then it run with the application.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SvcConfigEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732009.aspx) to edit your config files add tracing. Then open the trace files with [SvcTraceViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) to see if your calling the right services or you can find more info about the issue.